# Java: Casting to a type parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have the following two classes:

```
public class GenericNumberOperation {
    public GenericNumberOperation() {} 
    public <T extends Number> T getSomeValue (boolean tf) {
      T number;
      if(tf) {
          number = new Double(1.0);
      }
      else {
           number = new Integer(11);
      }
      return (T) number;
   }
}
```

And:

```
public class GenericNumberTest {
    public GenericNumberTest() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericNumberOperation gno = new GenericNumberOperation();
        Double d = gno.getSomeValue(true);
        Integer i = gno.getSomeValue(false);
    }
 }
```

When I run the test, everything is hunky-dory.  If I change the type parameterization to:

```
public <T> T getSomeValue(boolean tf)
```

The compiler complains, reporting:

error: incompatible types Integer cannot be converted to T 
  number = new Integer(11);
  where T is a type variable
  T extends Object declared in method getSomeValue(boolean)

It complains similarly about the Double. Why?

EDIT:
I made a mistake.  This is actually the code that works.

```
public class GenericNumberOperation {
    public GenericNumberOperation() {} 
    public <T extends Number> T getSomeValue (boolean tf) {
      Number number;
      if(tf) {
          number = new Double(1.0);
      }
      else {
           number = new Integer(11);
      }
      return (T) number;
   }
}
```

And now I understand what @Sotirios was getting at.

Comment: Why wouldn't it complain? What does an unbounded `T` type variable represnt?

Comment: It represents an object in an object cache.

Comment: No. I mean the type itself. What concrete type could you bind to it?

Comment: java.lang.Object? I'm guessing.  I have a natural fit for <T extends SomeBaseClass> so this is an academic question.

Comment: Andy, I *do* have an unsafe cast warning.  I am actually relying on the unsafe cast to cause the system assert.  If somehow the object cache is corrupted, I want it to assert.

Comment: But it is simply unsafe. You shouldn't be able to call `Float f = genOp.getSomeValue(true);`.

Comment: What Java version are you using? I can't reproduce your error. Also, I can't have `number = new Double(1.0)` (regardless of the generic declaration), I need a cast like this: `number = (T) new Double(1.0)`

Comment: java -version --> 1.8.0_40-b25

Comment: happy reading ... https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget about what you're trying to use this for. We're only going to look at this from a language perspective.

The declaration

```
public <T extends Number> T getSomeValue (boolean tf) {
```

defines a new type `T` that is bounded by `Number`. That means that a caller can only bind `Number` or any subtype of `Number` to `T` when invoking the method. Within the method, you don't know what that type might be.

You therefore can't do

```
T number = new Double(1.0);
```

because you don't know that `T` is `Double`. If I invoked the method as

```
Float f = genOp.getSomeValue(true);
```

`T` should have been `Float`. The compiler can't guarantee type safety and therefore rejects it (the assignment within the method, if it had been allowed, a `ClassCastException` would have been thrown at runtime). If you use a cast, you're telling the compiler that you're sure about what you're doing. It'll warn you, but it will trust you.

Similarly, the declaration

```
public <T> T getSomeValue(boolean tf)
```

defines a new type `T` that is unbounded. That means that you can bind any type to `T`, which makes the problem even greater. I can now do

```
String f = genOp.getSomeValue(true);
```

Comment: That's the essence of my confusion.  As I have written it [which I think is equivalent to what you wrote], the <T extends Number> parameterization compiles and runs with no issue.  I switched it up [called with false, with assignment to a double] and I got a runtime ClassCastException.  I understand your take to mean that it should never compile, let alone run.

Comment: @David Your first snippet should not compile as you've shown it.

Comment: I just double checked and it works.  It is a strange thing.

Comment: @David [You must not be running what you think you're running.](http://ideone.com/0wTnW6)

Comment: I copied your `GenericNumberOperation` class directly into Eclipse and it's giving the red-underlined compiler warning. I also tried to compile from the command-line using `javac GenericNumberOperation.java` and it fails. You said it compiles fine...what steps are you taking to do this exactly?

Comment: This is going to take some looking into.  I am now getting the errors that Sotirios got on ideone.  That said, I still have GenericNumberOperation.class from when it *did* compile.  javap reports:
Compiled from GenericNumberOperation.java
public class GenericNumberOperation {
public GenericNumberOperation();
public <T extends java.lang.Number> T getSomeValue(boolean);
}

Comment: I, unfortunately, can't get the file from that computer to this computer.

Answer (score -2):

As @Sotirios Delimanolis wrote, you cannot even run that code.

Try this one:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Number> T getSomeValue(boolean tf) {
    T number;
    if (tf) {
        number = (T) new Double(1.0);
    } else {
        number = (T) new Integer(11);
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that compiles, but he shouldn't be using that because he'd only be able to assign the result to a `Double` or `Integer`. Like @Sotirios said, `Float f = genOp.getSomeValue(true);` will throw an Exception.

Comment: Hmm, i've tried his code and it doesn't compile. It cannot be compliled, check it yourself if you do think so.
We cannot instantiate a *T* object with "new".

Comment: I did not use @SuppressWarnings and I am not interested in it.

Comment: @David, you can remove *SuppressWarnings*, it doesn't matter here.

Comment: `@SupressWarnings` is irrelevant. The point is that OP's original code doesn't compile, even though he claimed it did.

Comment: @DmitryDyokin *"We cannot instantiate a T object with "new""* Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see where he is doing that.

Comment: @Tom I'm talking about "*number = new Double(1.0);*", where "*number* has type *T*.

Comment: Ah damn, no I see that you're the one who wrote this answer ^^. So, nevermind :D.